# Updating Apollo cache after fetching data on server-side

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I spent 4 days in an attempt to get Apollo working with my Next.js app — and encountered a huge dilemma, as it seems.

Here's a very clear and understandable [example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates) for React SPA. This is how we update cache using mutation hook.

The mutation hook works with "todos" fields. Here's the excerpt:

```
fields: {
  todos(existingTodos = []) {
```

This implies that **a query has been made before**. The data was fetched via GraphQL query on the client-side. And the todos data has been cached as **"todos"** collection (or field rather).

So, with React SPA it is trivial to update the cache. And the work is easy and straightforward.

---

### Dilemma

In my Next.js app I fetch data **on server-side** in `getServerSideProps()` method. The fetched data is passed further to the Page Component as props.

When I perform a mutation **on client-side** — it's a different, an in-browser Apollo Client instance that doesn't have the cached data. Because that data was fetched using server-side instance.

---

**If it's not possible to access the Apollo server-side cache from the client-side (browser) — can someone recommend a workaround of how to go about Apollo with Next.js?**

Comment: Have you thought about passing the cache via props in `getServerSideProps` to the client and then updating the cache there in a `useEffect` hook?

Comment: @Gh05d Interesting. Haven't thought about it. Will investigate it now.